# Version and the affect on List View Thresholds

Tags: list, view, versioning, threshold

If a list has versioning enabled, is it only the current version that counts in the list view threshold limit?

Ex: 1 record has 3 older versions.  Does it count as 1 or 4?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, only the current version impacts the LVT.